# Change color of the dots in progress indicator Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, foreground, progress-indicator

Is it possible to change the color of the dots in the `ProgressIndicator` for a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application? I've set `Foreground` of my `ProgressIndicator` to white and it is colored white but the dots still remain blue.

[image: ProgressIndicator]

I'v noticed that Facebook have white dots in their `ProgressIndicator`, so is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the foreground color of Indeterminate progress bar by setting the following resource :

```
<x:String x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush">#EF9200</x:String>
```

This will change the foreground color of all the progress bar of your app.
But this won't work if you're using the system's progress indicator :

```
StatusBarProgressIndicator progressbar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ProgressIndicator;
        progressbar.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: The "ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" resource must be defined in your application ResourceDictionnary. If you do not have one, then add it in your app.xaml file

Comment: How do I add a ResourceDictionnary, do you have any good example? @Miiite

Comment: In your application's app.xaml file, at the top, simply add this  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>